# Using promises to wait for function to finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mocha.js

I've read some tutorials online for the Promises method but I'm still a bit confused.
I have a Node app.js which performs several functions including connecting to a db.

```
 db.connect(function(err) {
     setupServer();
     if(err) {
        logger.raiseAlarmFatal(logger.alarmId.INIT,null,'An error occurred while connecting to db.', err);
        return;
      }
```

Now I have written a mocha unit test suite, which encapsulates this app and performs several request calls to it. In some cases what occurs is that the the test initializes without confirmation that the db has successfully connected i.e: `setupServer()` has been performed.

How would I implement the promises method to this bit of asynchronous code, and if not promises, what should I use ? I have already tried event emitter but this still does not satisfy all the requirements and causes failures during cleanup.

Comment: what is inside setupServer? Is there async work in there?

Comment: it includes get/post/provisioning calls to set up keyspaces in the db

Comment: then you will need to setup promise inside the setupServer function.

Comment: You have to promisfy the db.connect function like new Promise((v,x) => db.connect... and then depending on the success or failure you should invoke the resolve or reject callbacks with the value or reason as an argument to those callbacks. Then you shall move on to the `then` method of the instantiated promise object for further processing in the same asynchronous timeline. (sorry i use `v` (looks like check) for resolve and `x` for reject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using mocha, you should use [asynchronous code approach](http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code). This way you can instruct mocha to wait for you to call `done` function before it goes on with the rest.

This would get you started:

```js
describe('my test', function() {
  before(function(done) {
    db.connect(function(err) {
      setupServer(done);
    });
  })

  it('should do some testing', function() {
     // This test is run AFTER 'before' function has finished
     // i.e. after setupServer has called done function
  });
});
```

assuming that your `setupServer` calls the `done` function when it's done:

```js
function setupServer(done) {
  // do what I need to do
  done();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `Promise` inside the body of function that has `async` work. For your case, I think that is `setupServer()` which you said contains ajax requests.

```
conts setupServer = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //async work
    //get requests and post requests
    if (true)
      resolve(result); //call this when you are sure all work including async has been successfully completed.
    else
      reject(error); //call this when there has been an error
  });
}


setupServer().then(result => {
  //...
  //this will run when promise is resolved
}, error => {
  //...
  //this will run when promise is rejected
});
```

For further reading:

- [Promise - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)